# How to achieve grouping in kendo grid with dynamic columns - asp.net core kendo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo asp.net core to render the kendo grid. I cannot find options to group,aggregate when dynamic columns are used to render the grid. Is there a solution that can be used by using asp.net core kendo?

Answer (score 0):

you must send proper data format to grid for that purpose in controller:

```
Enumerable<YourListDto> model_For_Aggregates = data;
return Json(model_For_Aggregates.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

and in your cshtml set as these:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.yourcolumn).Title("sample").ClientFooterTemplate("TotalCount: #=sum#");


.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Aggregates(aggregates =>
            {
                aggregates.Add(p => p.yourcolumn).Sum();
            })
           .Read
```